# confused about what a matrix represents

Tags: linear-algebra

how can it be that a matrix consists of vectors?
a matrix*"vectorx" product gives different result than a column of a matrix*"vectorx"

I had the feeling that I understood everything until linear transformations.
it is stated that the range of a transformation of some x is the span of the columns,
these columns are vectors rigth?

about the same idea: 
say we have 2 equations. 2x+3y and -1x+7y then put it in matrix A
the equations represent lines but the columns represent vectors, so those are not the same? what is the relation between the line and the vector?

I hope I'm explaining myself sufficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that the *interpretation* of the rows and the columns of a matrix depends on the problem where you face it. In your example of a system of linear equations, the rows represent the coefficients of the variables for each equation, while the first column represent the coefficient of $x$ for each equation, etc. You still can see the rows and the columns as vectors on their own.

Indeed, a matrix does consists of vectors. Depending on how you view it, those can be row or column-vectors. For example, the matrix
$$
A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\\pi&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}
$$
can be seen as consisting of the three column-vectors
$$
v_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\pi\\7\end{pmatrix},v_2:=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}\text{ and } v_3:=\begin{pmatrix}3\\6\\9\end{pmatrix},
$$
but can also be seen as consisting of the three row-vectors
$$
w_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix},w_2:=\begin{pmatrix}\pi&5&6\end{pmatrix}\text{ and } w_3:=\begin{pmatrix}7&8&9\end{pmatrix}.
$$
One instance of such views is the following. Suppose $x:=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ is a column-vector and you want to calculate $Ax$. The result can be written
$$
Ax=x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3,
$$
which tells us that the result is a linear combination of the column-vectors of $A$. That's why the range of a linear transformation (in finite dimension) is the span of the columns of its associated matrix. Similarly, if $y:=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is a row-vector, then
$$
yA=y_1w_1+y_2w_2+y_3w_3
$$
is a linear combination of the row-vectors of $A$.

Another instance of such view of a (square) matrix is when we define the determinant application via alternating multilinear $n$-forms, where $n$ is thought of as the number of column-vectors.

Comment: so if I understand correctly: in the process of linear transformations the interpretation of a matrix as a system of linear equations is cancelled, instead now the matrix represents a series of vectors?

Comment: @Erikzzz I'm not sure I understand your statement. When you have a system of linear equations, you can always form the matrix of coefficients. This matrix will consist of, say, $n$ rows and $m$ columns, and those rows and columns can be seen as vectors on their own.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks